# WordPress single page website redirect to index.html

Tags: rest-api, api

I have developer angular app from WordPress rest API.
I my WordPress baseURL and Angular app both are in same director (this is because WordPress and Angular URL are matched).
But in this setup issue is, when I direct open URL i.e. /blog or /anyPAGE, then it send request to WordPress instead of angular(index.html)
so is there a way to serve my app from index.html instead of index.php?

Answer (score 0):

yes, why not name your app's page app.html
it seems your hosting gives a priority to .php instead of .html
This is controlled by Apache's DirectoryIndex setting.

Comment: but how can I controlled this? can share some snippet?

Comment: What does google reveal when you search for DirectoryIndex  ?

Comment: yes, I already googled, it show <Directory "/foo">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
 and when I applied, it show 500 error

Comment: The second result shows: DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Comment: yes I already tried, its not use